# Rails 2.2.2 - Missing template error when trying to render a partial in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error when Rails tries to render my layout located in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**:

> Missing template shared/_header.erb in view path /home/me/checkout/site/app/views:
>   Extracted source (around line #11):
>   `8: <body>`
>   `9: <div id="wrap">`
>   `10: <div class="clear">...</div>`
>   `11:   <%= render :partial => 'shared/header' %>`

What's weird about all of this is that I have a directory named **shared** inside of **app/views**. Inside there I have a file named **_header.html.erb**.
I'm using Ruby 1.8.7, Rails
2.2.2, and following the documentation found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Update: Even more weirdness. This code works under Windows using InstantRails (Ruby 1.8.6, Rails 2.2.2). However, render :template doesn't seem to work. I'll keep on investigating.

Comment: Does `shared/_header.html.erb` have the same permissions, owner and group as `application.html.erb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been quite a while since I have touched Rails 2.2, but I believe that you are looking for the following:

```
<%= render :template => 'shared/header' %>
```

Edit: To whoever else is down down voting this, try reading the 2.2.2 docs and actually trying it first. This was a big gotcha back then.

Comment: According to the docs :template was required on Rails 2.2.2. Why they only mention it in a dark corner of the document is beyond me. I'm going to try this tonight at home. Also, I mistakingly downvoted your answer and just noticed now that the vote is locked. Please edit your answer so I can undo the downvote.

Comment: @enriquein That's cool. Give it a shot, and if it doesn't solve your problem then the next step would be to post some logs.

Comment: Right! Logs! Why didn't I think of that before? I was pretty much just reading Mongrel's output, but I keep forgetting the logs.

Answer (score 2):

If what you typed is correct, your partial is misnamed. It should be "_header.html.erb" and not "_header.erb.html". This is probably why Rails is not finding it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo in the question. The filename is correct.